# My code not work with wifi but when I add breakpoint it works

Tags: objective-c, debugging, voip, pjsip

in my voip App when I add breakpoint in wifi it works but when I remove breakpoint in wifi it doesn't work but in 4G and 3G it works. it is very strange, Thanks for any help.

here is my code but I don't think so if this is the problem.

```
- (void) smHoldCall {
    NSLog(@"Steve note: Hold the call here");
    LogDebug(TAG_SIP, @"__SM__ smHoldCall");

    pjsua_call_set_hold([call_id intValue], NULL);
}

- (void) smUnholdCall {


    LogDebug(TAG_SIP, @"__SM__ smUnholdCall");
    pjsua_call_reinvite([call_id intValue], PJ_TRUE, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Where was the breakpoint? Can you narrow it down to the specific line causing the issue?

Comment: @samiles, I added the breakpoint in code above: - (void) smHoldCall - (void) smUnholdCall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding :

```
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 4.0f ];
```